# Associated model not updated from nested JSON on update through proxy?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, model, proxy, extjs4

In my Ext JS 4.1 application, I have a model `Project` with an `belongsTo` association to `ProjectCategory`:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Project', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: ['id', 'project_category_id', 'title'],
  belongsTo: {
    model: 'MyApp.model.ProjectCategory',
    associationKey: 'ProjectCategory',
    getterName: 'getCategory'
  }
  // ...
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.ProjectCategory', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: ['id', 'title']
});
```

The project is read via a Direct proxy, and ProjectCategory details are included as nested values in the response (mostly for display purposes). When loading a store, the associated data is read correctly, and I'm able to read the `ProjectCategory`'s title in a grid via a custom renderer:

```
renderer: function(v, p, rec) {
  return v ? rec.getCategory().get('title') : '';
}
```

However, when editing and saving the parent `Project` record through `form.updateRecord(record)`, the associated record's fields aren't updated with values from the server response, unlike the `Project`'s "native" fields. So when changing the `project_category_id`, even though the server will respond with a correctly nested `ProjectCategory` field containing the new category, `getCategory` will still return the old category.

Why isn't this updated from the server response, and what do I have to do to update it?

I already found out that in the store's `write` listener, I have access to the record and the returned association data. But I can't figure out how to update the record silently without triggering any other events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like I found my solution. Add this to the `Project` store:

```
listeners: {
  write: function(store, operation, opt) {
    var c = operation.records[0].getCategory();
    c.set(operation.response.result.ProjectCategory);
    c.commit(true);
  }
}
```

The key element is the `commit(true)` call, which will skip notifying the store/proxy about the changes.

It's still a bummer that this isn't done automatically, though.

Comment: I encountered the same problem when I tried to access the parent record from the child record via the association getterName. I noticed that the actual record in the parent store is different from the one which the association retrieves. When I check the ext id attribute of each record (via 'record.id') they show different values. I'm sure there is a reason for this, but what I don't understand is why all the attributes (except maybe for the 'id'), don't match. It truly should be automatic.